# Probability - mega millions question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So here's the whole question (minus parts a,b because I'm only confused on c and d)...
2. A player in the Mega Millions lottery picks five different
integers between 1 and 56, inclusive, and a sixth integer
between 1 and 46, which may duplicate one of the earlier
five integers. The player wins the jackpot if the first five
numbers picked match the first five numbers drawn and
the sixth number matches the sixth number drawn.

c) What is the probability that a player wins $150 by
matching exactly three of the first five numbers and
the sixth number or by matching four of the first five
numbers but not the sixth number?

d) What is the probability that a player wins a prize, if a
prize is given when the player matches at least three
of the first five numbers or the last number.

$\def\c(#1,#2){\binom{#1}{#2}}$
So, for part C, I know we need to use the formula $$P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B).$$ Though, how do events A and B happen at the same time? It seems like they cannot bot happen at the same time, so I think the answer is:
$$\c(5,3)\c(51,2) + \c(5,4)\c(51,1)\c(45,1)\over  \c(56,6)\c(46,1)$$

For part D, I know we should take the complement, but again I'm having difficulty figuring out the $P(A\cap B)$. Would it be:
1-(ways to get 0, 1, or 2 numbers right, + ways to get last number right - ways to get both first 0,1,2 numbers right and last number right)

So, $$
1-\left(\c(51,5)\c(45,1) + \c(5,1)\c(51,4)\c(45,1) + \c(5,2)\c(51,3)\c(45,1)\right) + \c(51,5) - \left(\c(51,5) + \c(5,1)\c(51,4) + \c(5,2)\c(51,3)\right) \over \c(56,6)\c(46,1)
$$
Are these done correctly?

Comment: Oh I'll take the compliment. You should take the *complement*. :D

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva At least one of you is very handsome.

Comment: @Arkamis : One among who?

Comment: Your (c) is right.

Answer (score 1):

Your (c) is right.

For (d), we **lose** if we get $0$, $1$, or $2$ right on the first five, **and** we get the special sixth number wrong.

These events are **independent**.  So I suggest that you compute the probabilities separately, and multiply.

You know how to compute each probability. Multiply. If the result is $q$, then as you know the answer to (d) is $1-q$.

Comment: OK cool. I thought that was the case because I can't really tell how you the P(AnB) would work out in part d.

Comment: Formulas can be useful, but they come a distant second to analysis.